# Let $G$ be a group, if $H=\{b\in G\ |\ bab^{-1} \in \langle a \rangle\} $ is H a subgroup of G?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've seen this question around when $G\wedge\langle a \rangle$ are finite, but what if $G$ is infinite and $\langle a \rangle $ is finite?

My approach:

> 1. Show $H$ is closed, which just follows from the cyclicality of $\langle a \rangle$.
> 2. In the case that $G$ is infinite I also have to show that $\forall b \in H,\ b^{-1} \in H$.

I can't figure out how to show condition 2. I was hoping somone could help me out

Comment: Incase I can save anyone some time, to show 1. I used the fact $(bab^{-1})^n=ba^nb^{-1}$

Comment: If G be ableian then H=G and it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $b\in H$, since $c=bab^{-1}$ has the same order as $a$, it is a generator of $\langle a\rangle$. That is, $a=c^k$ for some $k$. Thus
$$b^{-1}ab=b^{-1}c^kb=b^{-1}(bab^{-1})^kb=a^k.$$
So $b^{-1}\in H$.

---

Note: the argument can be reversed. If $b,b^{-1}\in H$, then 
$$b^{-1}ab=a^k=b^{-1}c^kb.$$
So $a=c^k$, and $c$ is a generator of $\langle a\rangle$.

In the case $a$ has infinite order, it implies that $c=a$ or $c=a^{-1}$. So in general, $H$ is not a subgroup if $a$ has infinite order.

Comment: $c$ has the same oder with a, so it is a generator of ...?!

Comment: @RaziehNoori ... the group generated by $a$. What's wrong with it?

Comment: I was proving part 2 as OP asked. See edit for completeness.

Comment: what I don't see is why $c$ has the same order as $\langle a \rangle $. For example, if $c=a^2$ and $|\langle a \rangle | = 4$, then $|c|\neq 4$

Comment: $c^n=ba^nb^{-1}$: they should **both** be equal to $1$ or both different from $1$.

Comment: what about when $a$ has infinite order? @QuangHoang

Comment: conjugation is an automorphism so it preserves orders.

Comment: The OP asked for the case $a$ had finite order. In the other case, i think we can construct a conterexample $\langle a,b: bab^{-1}=a^2\rangle$.

Comment: But since $\langle a \rangle $ is finite, the most we can say is that the order of $bab^{-1} $ divides the order of $a$, not that $\|bab^{-1}\| = \| a\| $

Comment: But $c=b^{-1}ab$ and the same argument applies.